# SQL Syntax for joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need to query from 3 different tables based upon certain WHERE criteria

My Tables are :

```
1. tb_jemaat
2. tb_absenir
3. tb_absenonid
```

Below are the structure of every single table I have

```
tb_jemaat
id_jemaat (PK), name
tb_absenir date, 
id_jemaat (FK), time, tib   
tb_absenonid date, name, tib
```

All I want to do is to show date,name from tb_absenir and tb_absenonid

Below are the sql syntax I have but it results error

```
SELECT ir.tanggal, j.nama 
FROM tb_absenir as ir inner join tb_jemaat as j 
on j.id_jemaat = ir.id_jemaat left join tb_absenonid 
WHERE (ir.tanggal = '" & Format(dtp_ir.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'And nonid.tanggal = '" & Format(dtp_ir.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "') and ir.tib = '" & tib & "'
```

I am using Mysql and VB.Net 2010

Comment: I believe you are missing a join clause for the left join

Comment: You have no ON condition associated with your OUTER JOIN

Comment: Please edit your question and show what the query looks like *after* the variable substitution.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion, I will try my best and show what it looks like